# Assign Values in Column from Substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Pandas and have a hard time figuring out the best way to solve the below problem:

I have a Dataframe with one column called Email like below:

```
Email
abc@yahoo.com
defg@gmail.com
NAN
ghi@yahoo.com
jkl@gmail.com.it
```

I separated the strings on '@' to create a Domain column and want to use that column to assign keywords in a new column. For instance, if the domain contains the word 'yahoo', call it 'Yahoo Account' in the new column. If it does not contain the word 'yahoo', assign it the value 'Other Domain', and if it is NaN, call it 'Unknown'.

The new column called Affiliation would look like:

```
Affiliation 
Yahoo Account 
Other Domain 
Unknown 
Yahoo Account 
Other Domain
```

There are over 2,000 different types of domains so am looking for a way where I don't list and map all the unique domains as either being "Yahoo Account" or "Other Domain."

I have looked into a few options, one of which is the where clause, but it assigns NaN values to the Other Domain keyword.

```
df['Affiliation'] = np.where(df['Domain']=='yahoo', 'Yahoo Account', 'Other Domain')
```

I have also started to look at using the replace clause, but don't think this is the best way due to the amount of unique domains there are that would need to be added to other_affiliations. See below:

```
yahoo_affiliations = (r'(yahoo\S*)')
other_affiliations= (r'(gmail\S*)|(hotmail\S*)|(outlook\S*)')

# Create a new column called Affiliation from Domains
df['Affiliation'] = df['Domain']

# Fill NaN with Unknwon
df['Affiliation']  = df['Affiliation'].fillna('Unknown')

replacements = {
           'Affiliation': {yahoo_affiliations: 'Yahoo Account',
                                        other_affiliations: 'Other Domain'}
                        }

df.replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You have managed to separate the strings? Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: Yes I have looked through the docs and on StackOverflow - I just tried to clarify a bit more. Thanks for asking for more information!

Comment: Is the answer by opressionslayer alright? You don't need to assign the intermediate Series to your DataFrame by the way, I think he did it just for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can split them like this to get your mappings

```
email_map = {'yahoo.com': 'Yahoo Account',
'gmail.com': 'Other Domain',
'gmail.com.it': 'Other Domain' 
}
dfa['domain'] = dfa['Email'].str.extract(r'.*?@(.*)') 
dfa['Affiliation'] = dfa['domain'].map(email_map).fillna('Unknown')
```

output:

```
              Email        domain    Affiliation
0     abc@yahoo.com     yahoo.com  Yahoo Account
1     def@gmail.com     gmail.com   Other Domain
2               NAN           NaN        Unknown
3     ghi@yahoo.com     yahoo.com  Yahoo Account
4  jkl@gmail.com.it  gmail.com.it   Other Domain
```

Comment: Thanks oppressionslayer! I was hoping to avoid creating something like email_map because there are over 2,000 unique domains I would have to assign to 'Other Domain'. I realized that wasn't obvious so edited my question after seeing your response!